# How to collect the graphics element drawn on a graphics layer?

Tags: arcobjects

The graphics element may consist of point, circles, polygon, free hand line drawing or marker symbols.

I m using arcobjects.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and state exactly what you're trying\need to do -it is not clear from what you've written. Please state what software you're using as the solution differs between softwares. Oh, and welcome to GIS.se !

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the IMap to IGraphicsContainer, call IGraphicsContainer.Reset then iterate through each IElement. See sample [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8091/how-to-collect-the-graphics-element-drawn-on-a-graphics-layer).